# Cut from the third decimal without rounding

Tags: javascript, math, tofixed

I know it's quite low quality of question but I get little bit confused now. 
Here is the thing What I want to do.

```
100000 => 100.000
9997080000 => 9997080.000
```

I want to cut from the third decimal without rounding.
How can I do this? I used the `toFixed()` but all I want to do is just cut from third decimal. I think I'm complicated now.
It will be simple. Plz let me know. Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you need to accomplish. Do you need to divide the number by 1000?

Comment: @rachel_hong What do you want  to do here? 5000 should be 5? You want  to divide a number by 1000?

Comment: Do all your numbers have more than 4 digits? Or you also have numbers like 100, 10, 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is what you want:

```js
var number = "9002764000";
var result = number.slice(0, -3) +"."+ number.slice(-3);
console.log(result);
```

This will add a `.` after the last three digits i.e `9002764000` -> `9002764.000`

https://jsfiddle.net/5yqhr7mo/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a value for *display*. If so, you want to turn the number into a string (since *numbers* don't intrinsically have any particular number of digits to the right of the decimal). You can then easily insert the `.` before the last three digits using [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```js
function formatForDisplay(num) {
  var str = String(num);
  return str.substring(0, str.length - 3) + "." + str.substr(-3);
}

function test(num) {
  console.log(num, "=>", formatForDisplay(num));
}

test(100000);
test(9997080000);
```

Comment: `toFixed` uses rounding. `Math.floor` does not. (if that is important for op)

Comment: @NinaScholz: The `toFixed` was applied to a *whole number*, so there's no rounding. (But the reason I was using `toFixed` was flawed, I've changed it to just `String`.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and add a dot.

```js
var number = 9002764000;

console.log(Math.floor(number).toString().replace(/(?=...$)/, '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```js
function formatNumber(num){
 num=num/1000;
 return num.toFixed(3);
}
console.log(formatNumber(9997080000));
console.log(formatNumber(100000000));
```

which will return what you expect if you work with integer

Answer (score -1):

`Math.floor()` will round down essentially cutting off everything to the right of decimal point.